# How to handle a situation in which you accidentally harm some content in a users post?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39487/if-imis-was-updated-to-be-partially-reusable-and-implemented-by-nasa-what-are) and clicked the link out of curiosity. It brought up the GoogleDocs application on my iPad (that is what I usually browse on) and the keyboard came up. I hit the back key and it wiped everything out. It autosaved the changes when I exited the app. **I feel completely horrible about this and I would like to know how the community thinks I should handle this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google docs retains a revision history of your files if I remember correctly, so your owner should be ok to recover their content.

Obviously make sure you let them know...

Comment: Already let them know. I am glad they can get their work back. I really need to be much more careful, but it happened pretty fast.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan yeah at times google docs isn't intuitive